# Safari Web Extension - Package Dependency in Shared Code

Tags: ios, swift, macos, safari, swift-package-manager

I'm new to extension development, only having working on iOS apps in the past, so this may be a simple issue.

I am trying to use a Swift Package Manager-installed dependency (SwiftSoup) in my shared extension handler code, but it doesn't recognize the installed package.

I created a new Multiplatform web extension project named testExtension.

This creates the following folders:

- Shared (App)
- Shared (Extension)
- iOS (App)
- macOS (App)
- iOS (Extension)
- macOS (Extension)

But only the following Targets

- testExtension (iOS)
- testExtension (macOS)
- testExtension Extension (iOS)
- testExtension Extension (macOS)

The SafariWebExtensionHandler is defined in the Shared (Extension) folder, which isn't directly tied to a target.  When I try to import the package, I get "No such module 'SwiftSoup'."

Comment: For the downvote of my original question, could you provide a reason?  It's unclear to me why Apple's default template creates a folder for the shared handler that is not tied to a target, making it impossible (as far as I could tell) to use external packages in the shared code.  I did search for several hours before posting, and could not find an obvious answer.  My solution (below) may not be the best, so I was hoping someone with safari extension development might have an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but I added a handler class to testExtension Extension (macOS) and testExtension Extension (iOS) targets and modified the Info.plist in each to point to the new handler classes instead of the original shared one (using NSExtensionPrincipalClass).  I should be able to move the shared code to a protocol in the (Shared) Extension folder to eliminate code duplication.